# unable to send sms via smpp account

Tags: java, smpp

i tried to send sms via smpp account and i have the error "'Must be bound to the SMSC before sending packets", the problem is that when i checked the smpp account, it is connedcted to SMSC, but sms are not going, sms are not even reaching the SMSC. please can somebody help

Answer (score 1):

the SMPP protocol expects the client to

- connect
- authenticate

you need to identify the user credentials for your client and authenticate before you send an sms to the Gateway.

also, the SMPP server must be returning an error code, it would be helpful to post that as well.